# find particular column where string is match

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have one file test.sh. In this my content is look like

```
Nas /mnt/enjayvol1/backup/test.sh lokesh
thinclient rsync /mnt/enjayvol1/esync/lokesh.sh lokesh
crm rsync -arz --update /mnt/enjayvol1/share/mehul mehul mehul123
```

I want to retrieve string where it match content /mnt

I want output line

```
/mnt/enjayvol1/backup/test.sh
/mnt/enjayvol1/esync/lokesh.sh
/mnt/enjayvol1/share/mehul
```

I have tried

```
grep -i "/mnt" test.sh | awk -F"mnt" '{print $2}'
```

but this will not give me accurate output. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short **grep** approach (assuming that ***/mnt...*** path doesn't contain whitespaces):

```
grep -o '\/mnt\/[^[:space:]]*' lokesh.sh
```

The output:

```
/mnt/enjayvol1/backup/test.sh
/mnt/enjayvol1/esync/lokesh.sh
/mnt/enjayvol1/share/mehul
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following awk approach too and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v RS=" " '$0 ~ /\/mnt/'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
/mnt/enjayvol1/backup/test.sh
/mnt/enjayvol1/esync/lokesh.sh
/mnt/enjayvol1/share/mehul
```

**Explanation:** Making record separator as space and then checking if any line has /mnt string in it, if yes then not mentioning any action so by default print will happen. So it will print those lines which have /mtn sting in them.

Comment: You don't have to escape /mnt/